# Overlay UIImage Array with UIImage Array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an array of images and then those images get a watermark applied to them. I am trying to make the watermark animated when it is overlaid on the images. Basically I have an array of images that are taken from the camera then I have an array of images for the watermark that matches the number of photos taken. What I am trying to figure out is how to apply each watermark image to the corresponding number in the array of photos taken.

For example, I take 4 photos, I have a watermark array of 4 images. I need watermark number one to go over photo taken number one, watermark two over photo taken two, etc. The code below is my normal code which is for a single photo. I just can't seem to find a way to apply one array over another.

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.arrSlidshowImg.count; i++)
  {
    _flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self makedesign];         
  }


- (void)makedesign

  {
    NSData *bgimage = self.record.watermark;
    UIImage *backgroundImage = _flippedImage;
    UIImage *watermarkImage = [UIImage imageWithData:bgimage];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImage.size);
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height)];
    [watermarkImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(backgroundImage.size.width - watermarkImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height - watermarkImage.size.height, watermarkImage.size.width, watermarkImage.size.height)];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   }
```

Comment: Create an array of watermarks (let's call it `arrWatermark`). In the for loop do only `[self makedesignWithImageData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i] andWatermarkData:[_arrWatermark objectAtIndex:i]];`, with `- (void)makedesignWithImageData:(NSData *)imageData andWatermarkData:(NSData *)waterMark{ UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]; UIImage *watermarkImage = [UIImage imageWithData:waterMark];`//rest of the code of `makedesign`?

Comment: Thanks Larme. I am going to try that now. That makes sense.